# javascript truncate string without including punctuation or space

Tags: javascript, slice

this is my attempt for truncate a string

```
String.prototype.truncate = function (num) {
  var str = this;
    if (str.length > num && num > 3 ) { 
        console.log(str.length);
        return str.slice(0, num) + "..."; 

    } else if (str.length > num && num <= 3) {
        console.log('ok');
        return str.slice(0, num) + "...";

    } else {
        console.log(str.length);
        return str;
    }

}
```

please any body, know how to resolve it, thanks

````
'Hello world!'.truncate(2) ====> 'He...'
'Hello world!'.truncate(6) ====> 'Hello...');
'Hello, world!'.truncate(6)====> 'Hello...');```
````

Comment: Why two different conditions with `num > 3` and `num <= 3` for the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove extra spaces and [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace last character if `,` by `''` and finally add the `...`

Code:

```js
String.prototype.truncate = function(num) {
  return `${this.slice(0, num).trim().replace(/\,$/, '')}...`;
}

console.log('Hello world!'.truncate(2));  // ====> 'He...'
console.log('Hello world!'.truncate(6));  // ====> 'Hello...'
console.log('Hello, world!'.truncate(6)); // ====> 'Hello...'
```

According to your comment:

```js
String.prototype.truncate = function(num) {
  const str = this.slice(0, num).trim().replace(/\,$/, '');
  return str[str.length - 1] !== '!' ? `${str}...`: str;
}

console.log('Hello world!'.truncate(2));  // ====> 'He...'
console.log('Hello world!'.truncate(6));  // ====> 'Hello...'
console.log('Hello, world!'.truncate(6)); // ====> 'Hello...'
console.log('Hi!'.truncate(5));           // ====> 'Hi!'  <---- On the comments
```

Comment: thank you, please how can i customize this for that case.
'Hello world!'.truncate(2) ===> 'He...
'Hello'.truncate(5) ===> 'Hello'
'Hi!'.truncate(5) ===>  'Hi!'

Comment: Then make a condition to add the `...` if different of `!`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to construct a regular expression that matches `num - 1` word characters, possibly preceeded by any number of non-word characters (like spaces and punctuation):

```js
String.prototype.truncate = function (num) {
  const pattern = new RegExp(`(?:\\W*\\w){${num - 1}}`);
  return this.match(pattern)[0] + '...';
}
console.log('Hello, world!'.truncate(6))
```